# 404 error given when using flowbite components with vite, vue, vue router and tailwindcss

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, node-modules, vue-router, vite

I've tried to use Flowbite components within my Vite project, originally this was working fine. I was able to create a carousel that animated, however after installing vue-router no Flowbite javascript elements are working and instead are hitting this error in the web console when instantiating a new component from Flowbite.

```
Could not load content for http://localhost:5173/node_modules/flowbite/src/components/dropdown/index.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)
```

I've followed the docs perfectly, and can't seem to figure out why they're suddenly not working, if it's because of vue-router I don't understand why. This is the state of my tailwind.config.js:

```
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily:{
        'primary': ['Montserrat'],
        'secondary': ['Esteban']
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
  darkMode: 'class'
}
```

I've tried to re-install npm packages, and restart my server to see if it was a local issue but nothing. I've tried multiple Flowbite js components and none work. I've looked and looked on the web to see if this is an issue for anyone else but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: ` 'node_modules/flowbite-vue/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'`?

Comment: please provide your router codes.

Comment: did you see this? https://flowbite-vue.com/

Comment: I've installed flowbite-vue, and have added the necessary reference to content in my tailwind.config.js. I'm still getting this error appearing whenever i add the example carousel from the flowbite docs: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/carousel/